# Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, xcode8, appdelegate

I started working on the app before the release of Xcode8 and and then switched over , When I try to log into the app using Facebook login I get the following error

> Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: GhostGab.AppDelegate

I checked all the settings and they seemed fine . Any help will be appreciated

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FIRApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}

  func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return facebookDidHandle
}
```

Comment: which syntax you are working on 2.3 or 3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function definition:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
}
```

Should be replaced by:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
}
```

There's an underscore for the first parameter and `Any` in place of `AnyObject` for the last parameter type.

That's why you're getting the error:

> Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was the problem